# Get DDL of all tables in a postgresql schema

Tags: postgresql-12

I need to get the "CREATE TABLE" statements for all the tables in a particular schema of postgreSQL. How can I do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name
I can use pg_dump. I'll try this option.